# jQuery post() to php page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm learning php/javascript so don't smile...

I try from page1.php to post 3 variables to page2.php.
I'm not sure what's wrong...
Here is the code (simplified mode):

**page1.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = post_text;
function post_text() {
test1="111";
test2="222";
test3="333";
$.post("page2.php", { test1:test1 , test2:test2, test3=test3 });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
$a=$_POST['test1'];
$b=$_POST['test2'];
$c=$_POST['test3'];
echo $a.$b.$c;
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Check the `=` in `test1:test1 , test2:test2, test3=test3`

Comment: What's not working? I can tell you that you are missing your callbacks. [See $.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). This is an `ajax` call so your browser is not going to navigate to that page for you to view. The `echo` will return the results of the script on `page2.php` to `page1.php`. It's up to you to properly handle the returned result and do something with it.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.post("page2.php", { test1:test1 , test2:test2, test3:test3 });
```

Comment: `$.post("page2.php", { test1:test1 , test2:test2, test3=test3 });` whats difference between yours and op

Comment: @NullPointer The OP typed `=` where it should have been a `:`.

Comment: i am really not able to find = where it should :

Comment: @NullPointer - object literals are key value pairs where each key and value are separated by a colon. example {foo : "bar"} not {foo = "bar"}

Comment: Ok. Thanks for answers. Nothings happened after page1 execution. No error on console, no page2 displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are learning, you might try to isolate problems by writing shorter chunks of code and seeing if they work first. In this case your first problem is an ordinary typo (test3=test3, instead of test3: test3) so your whole JS does not parse. You should be seeing the relevant error message in the firebug console (or chrome console).

Comment: Thanks. Is not a problem with "=" (I made a mistake on pasting/adapting code on posted question). After parsing page1 - no error code on console, no page2 displayed. That's my problem. Thank you for patience ;)

Comment: frankly, it's hard to help you: you don't seem to even know what is it you want to do. Why on earth should page2 be displayed? It is an ajax call, it shouldn't display anything! Did you or did you not check the console (the network tab)?